# Why is this multithreaded program getting stuck at infinite loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, producer-consumer

The below program is a simple threaded program . For some reason which i am not able to figure , its getting stuck at infinite loop of both produce() and consume() methods simultaneously in both the threads.

It produces the output for a few times and then there is no output at the console. So I presume its getting stuck at the loop.

My question is , since the loop depends on the value of the flag `valueSet` of the same object of Item class , `valueSet` can't be both true and false at the same time . So either of the produce() or cosume() method's loop should get false and the printing of output should continue.

But that's not happening here. So why is it getting stuck at the while loop if the condition depends on the flag variable which can only take true or false at a time ?

```
class Item{
    boolean valueSet = false ; 
    int item = 0 ; 

    public  void consume(){
        while(!valueSet) ;
        System.out.println("Consumed : "  + item ) ; 
        valueSet = false ;
    }

    public  void produce(int n ){
        while(valueSet);
        item = n ;
        System.out.println("Produced : "  + item ) ; 
        valueSet = true ;
    } 
}

class Producer implements Runnable{
 Item item ;
 Producer(Item itemobj){
     item = itemobj ; 
 }

 public void run(){
     while(true){
         System.out.println("\nProducing ....") ; 
     item.produce((int)Math.random()*100) ; 
     }
 }

}

class Consumer implements Runnable{
    Item item  ;
    Consumer(Item itemobj){item = itemobj ; }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            System.out.println("\nConsuming !") ;
        item.consume() ; 

        }
    }
}


class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item item = new Item() ;
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(item)) ; 
        Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(item)) ;
        System.out.println("\nStarted producer and consumer threads : ") ; 
        consumer.start() ; 
        producer.start() ; 
    }
}
```

**Update :**

When the `while(valueSet)` is stuck at infinite loop in one thread , shouldn't `while(!valuSet)` get out of loop and flip the `valueSet`? This would inturn cause `while(valueSet)` to come out of loop right ?

As per some answers it seems when `while(valueSet)` is stuck , the other thread is somehow not able to access `valueSet` . **I don't understand how this is happening. Please explain your answer.**

I see that using `volatile` for `valueSet` will fix it but i am not able to understand how without using it. It's causing the infinite loop even if it depends on one flag `valueSet` which can't be true and false at the same time.

Comment: I'm not a multi-threaded Java expert, but I don't seen any sort of synchronization between your producer and consumer.  I might expect something like a deadlock or a livelock here.  Check for examples to see how to handle this sort of problem.

Comment: Make `valueSet` `volatile`. I'd also consider using a monitor lock over a free wheeling loop - you will get better performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, what you're trying to do here is to use `valueSet` as a boolean flag to synchronize the `Consumer` and `Producer` -- to make them work in turn. It is true that `valueSet` can only be true or false at one moment; however, it's not how the two threads (Consumer and Producer) view it.

We know that in Java, objects are stored on the **heap**; that is called the **main memory**. For each thread, however, for performance's sake, references to used objects are kept in a thread-specific **cache**. As in here, `Producer` and `Consumer` share one `Item` object which is stored on the heap; the field `item.valueSet` might be cached by each thread.

```
 _______________    ______________  
 |   Consumer    |  |   Producer   |  
 |   _________   |  |   _________  |  
 |  |         |  |  |  |         | |  
 |  | Cache1  |  |  |  |  Cache2 | |  
 |  | valueSet|  |  |  | valueSet| |
 |  |_________|  |  |  |_________| |  
 |_______________|  |______________|
           | |              | |
           | |              | |
          _|_|______________|_|__
         |                       |
         |      MAIN MEMORY      | 
         |      valueSet         | 
         |_______________________|
```

When, say, `Consumer` changes `valueSet` to `false`, it might or might not flush the new value to the main memory; similarly, when `Producer` checks `valueSet`, it might or might not try to read the newest value from the main memory. That's where the `volatile` keyword comes into play. When you set `valueSet` to be `volatile`, it ensures that both threads write/read the newest value to/from main memory.

Notice that the above summary is bascially known as the **JVM Memory Model**. It's a set of rules to define JVM's behaviour under multithreading situations.

If you try changing the following parts of your code:

```
    **volatile** boolean valueSet = false ; 
    **volatile** int item = 0 ;
    ...
    item.produce((int)(Math.random()*100)) ; // added parenthesis
```

You will see following output:

```
Started producer and consumer threads : 

Consuming !

Producing ....
Produced : 83

Producing ....
Consumed : 83

Consuming !
Produced : 54

Producing ....
Consumed : 54

Consuming !
Produced : 9

Producing ....
Consumed : 9

Consuming !
Produced : 23

Producing ....
Consumed : 23
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you will need to make that shared variable `volatile`.

A thread is allowed to put its local variables in a register, so yes, one thread can see `valueSet` as false and the other can see it as `true`. At the same time. Make the variable `volatile` to force it to be read from memory each time.

However, this will not guarantee there are no other problems with the code. Synchronization can be tricky. But research `volatile` to get past the most likely cause.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, as I'm not an expert at Java, but try writing your while loop like this:

```
public  void consume(){
    while(!valueSet) {
        System.out.println("Consumed : "  + item ) ; 
        valueSet = false ;
    }
}
```

Loops need content after wards inside curly brackets just like functions and for loops do. Your while loop *could* be getting stuck because it never gets to valueSet = false because it never actually properly initiates the loop.

Answer (score 1):

U should set the `valueSet` to `volatile` to make the variable visible for the two threads.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `Item`'s blocking with `while()`.

If `valueSet` is set to `True` then `while(valueSet);` will wait forever, locking `Item`

Same for `while(!valueSet);`. This is a deadlock.

Comment: But when the while(valueSet) is stuck at infinite loop in one thread , shouldn't while(!valuSet) get out of loop and flip the valueSet . This would inturn cause while(valueSet) to come out of loop right ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **volatile** variable "valueSet" because:

- "valueSet" is shared variable for Producer and Consumer
- Your threads Producer & Consumer are using local copy of your variable "valueSet", which brings your code to a possibility that it might be true (OR false) for both at the same time

Also:

Using **volatile** ensures that

- your threads Producer & Consumer will **read** shared volatile variable "valueSet" directly from main memory that will be latest (No possibility of valueSet being true Or false at the same time)
- If there is a **write** going on your volatile variable "valueSet" by Producer or Consumer, and suddenly a read is requested by either of your threads, it is guaranteed that the **write** operation will be finished prior to the read operation.