# Using an extended Thread trough two instances of it's class is causing skipping of values

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the next sample I am trying to run, but sometimes it runs fine, another it is not exiting the loop. I can imagine only that for some reason values are skipping.
By skipping the values I mean the flags meant to notify the loop in the class Flasher to exit, which are brought from class engine, ass well the flags meant to notify the loop in class Engine from class Flasher.
This is how I understood it could run the best possible and simplest way, but what is going on?
Can you please help?

```
//Main class:
    public class Flasher {
        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            engine en1 = new engine("ZaikoBaiko");
            engine en2 = new engine("MiliVaninili");
            en1.start();
            en2.start();
            int Terminator2 = 0;
            while(!en1.Terminator||!en2.Terminator)
            {
            }
            System.out.println(" owns the last word");
            en1.roboCop = true;
            en2.roboCop = true;
        }
        
    }

//Thread Class:

public class engine extends Thread
{   
    public String OB;
    public boolean Terminator = true;
    public boolean roboCop = false;
    private Thread t;
    engine(String name)
    {
       OB = name;
       Terminator = false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int x = 0;
        while(x<100)
        {
            System.out.println(x+":"+OB);
        x++;
        }
        Terminator = true;
        while(!roboCop){}
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start()
    {
        if(t==null)
        {
            t = new Thread(this,OB);
            t.start();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! I have found that removing the System.out.println() from the loop of engine() is fixing the issue. Still what is it causing and how to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM is caching your variables. You need to add volatile to your check variables (Terminator, roboCop). This will ensure that all threads write/read the newest value to/from main memory.

For a detailed explanation here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52694526/why-is-this-multithreaded-program-getting-stuck-at-infinite-loop)!

Comment: Thank you very much! Good to learn something new today.